# Why is the highscore reset when the game starts again?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2D game in Unity. I'm stuck on the high score part. When the game starts, the score and the high score go together, but when the game ends and I press play again, the high score is reset. what is the reason of this?
Thank you from now.

```
public Text scoreText;
public Text highscoreText;

private float score = 0;
private float highScore = 0;

public Transform cam;

public GameObject panel;

private bool moveLeft;
private bool moveRight;
private float horizontalMove;


void Update()
{
    if (rb.velocity.y > 0 && transform.position.y > score)
    {
        score = transform.position.y;
    }
    scoreText.text = Mathf.Round(score).ToString();

    if (cam.position.y > transform.position.y + 7f)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        panel.SetActive(true);
    }
    
    if (score > highScore)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("highScore", highScore);
        highscoreText.text = "HIGHSCORE: " + Mathf.Round(score).ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

    }
    
    MovementPlayer();
}

public void PlayAgain()
{
    PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("highScore");
    highscoreText.text = "HIGHSCORE: " + Mathf.Round(highScore).ToString();

    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}

private void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    moveLeft = false;
    moveRight = false;

    Time.timeScale = 1;

    PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("highScore");
    highscoreText.text = highScore.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I think this is your mistake. I think you meant to store 'score', not 'highscore' here: 
`PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("highScore", highScore);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isn't problem here? You are not update your player prefs with actual score but with old highscore?

```
if (score > highScore)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("highScore", highScore);
```

it should be

```
PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("highScore", score);
```

Comment: That and also set highScore = score, because otherwise that code block including "PlayerPrefs.Save();" is executed every frame which can quickly be a performance issue. In fact it would also make sense to call the Save() function only once in: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't work. I think there is a problem in the start or play again part. In the game, the score and the high score increase in the same way. There is no problem at the end of the game. When the game starts by pressing play again, the high score is reset.

Comment: GetFloat return float, but you did not store in any variable... you used "PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("highScore");" but it should be "highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("highScore");" look here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetFloat.html